# Accessing HttpContext.Session from static method

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am getting following error when accessing HttpContext.Session from static method placed in separate task:

> Session has not been configured for this application or request.

I used [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/a-better-approach-to-access-httpcontext-outside-a-controller-in-net-core-2-1/) to implement access to HttpContext outside the controller

From controller I invoke this static method that used to retrieve image data:

```
public static void CreateDummyGallery(Gallery gallery)
{
    Logger.LogDebug(LogModule.Dummy, $"Starting gallery creation.");
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            List<DummyPicture> pictures;
            using (var context = new MyzeumContext())
            {
                int top = 10;
                pictures = context.DummyPictures.FromSql($"SELECT * FROM dummypictures ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT {top}").ToList();
            }
            Logger.LogDebug(LogModule.Dummy, $"Starting retrieving images.");
            Parallel.ForEach(pictures, picture => {
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                 }
             });
            Logger.LogDebug(LogModule.Dummy, $"Done retrieving images.");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Logger.LogError(LogModule.Server, e.Message, e);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem occurs in Logger.LogDebug() because this is where I access HttpContext:

```
public void LogDebug(LogModule module, string message, Exception stackTrace = null)
{
    Log record = new Log();
    record.Module = module;
    record.ThreadId = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId;
    record.SessionId = HttpContextHelper.Current?.Session?.Id;
    record.Message = message;
    record.Logged = DateTime.UtcNow;
    if(stackTrace != null)
    {
        record.Message += $" :{stackTrace.StackTrace}";
    }
    queue.Enqueue(record);
}
```

The problem 99% occurs in the first call inside task:

```
Logger.LogDebug(LogModule.Dummy, $"Starting retrieving images.");
```

BUT, right after application starts this whole task block works fine and does not throw any exception. Problem starts after following requests.

Comment: The pure requirement should tell you very clearly, that your design isn't good if you need to **statically**  access something, **that's only available during a request**. Redesign your code, read the docs to see how to use dependency injection and you won't have this issues

Comment: But the problem in this case is not static access but task. In static access everything works fine

Comment: That's what @Tseng is saying. You're using a static method that needs to interact with captive dependencies. That's a universal no-no. The whole design is wrong on its face, so the "fix" is to design it properly. You could use a singleton class instead of statics, for example. You'd then need to utilize a service locator, which is itself an anti-pattern, but it's still better than using statics.

Comment: And on a side note, your method is fire and forget: you start a task with `Task.Factory.StartNew(` and don't await it, so your request ends. When your code executes afterwards, how do you expect it to access the HttpContext which itself only exist during the request

Comment: How does your HttpContextHelper look like? Can you post code for it?

Comment: Rob, I already refactored the code. Thanks